# Uses Deprecated API (Expect-ct) but there is no expect-ct header on my website

Tags: api, deprecated, pagespeed

I have a deprecated API on the google page speed test "Uses deprecated APIs 1 warning found
Deprecated APIs will eventually be removed from the browser. Learn more.
Deprecation / Warning
Source
...
https://www.chaise-de-gamer.fr :0:-1 "

The problem is that it doesn't shows what's the problem.

Before that, I had two deprecated APIs, but since I had expect-ct on my htaccess, I removed it, and one warning disappeared.

The thing is that when I go to the console on Google Chrome, I still have a warning that I use a deprecated feature (Expect-ct again) but the thing is that none of my headers returns Expect-ct and I still have that warning on pagespeed as well and I've already removed it from my htaccess and reloaded my cache many times.

Do you have an idea what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i am in the same situation. No header returned but pagespeed tools tells me that i should remove it. I only have a doubt of 3rd parties included from javascript.